# Installing new gas water heater

Tags: pipe, gas

I want to install a new gas water heater in a different location then my current Electric water heater. It will be more central to both bathrooms. The proposed location is shown in blue here:

[image: Gasline4]

I will be tapping into a 3/4" T, located next to and above the gas furnace, here:

[image: Gasline1]

The line from the T to the 90 degree elbow is 3/4". The vertical pipe is 1/2" into furnace:

[image: Gasline3]

The proposed gas line will run approx. 22" straight out from T, then make a right, over to far wall, then turn again toward new water heater proposed location(orange line in the top picture).

Question: Do I need to run the proposed pipe to new heater location as 3/4" pipe, then change to 1/2" for vertical run down to new heater? OR can I just reduce pipe near the T and run 1/2" pipe all the way to heater. Approximate total run of pipe would be about 40 feet.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Those pictures would be useful, but you didn't include them. Would you edit your question with them? If you aren't allowed to post the pictures, post the URLs and someone will be along to edit them in.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no URL's. These pics are from my personal pic folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have more useful pictures? If not, then you're fine.